# How do I resolve 404 with custom static web app auth?

Tags: asp.net, azure, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I followed the following articles:

- https://jsandersrocksblog.github.io/2021/07/02/walkthrough-static-web-apps-and-aad-authentication.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad

However I still get a 404 on https://calm-field-007794403.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/aad even though my settings looks correct?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are struggling with the same problem. It turns out that these two fields HAVE to be the name of settings and cannot be direct inputs.

[image]

Comment: @Mudrock Can u share ur routing config from staticwebapp.config.json